# How to increase the TCP "receive window"on the iPhone

Tags: objective-c, c, sockets, tcp

I only seem to be able to receive a max stream size of 8k bytes.  It craps out after that.  How can I enlarge this?  thx

```
    host = gethostbyname("xxx"); 

    memcpy(&(sin.sin_addr), host->h_addr, host->h_length);
    sin.sin_family = host->h_addrtype;
    sin.sin_port = htons(4000);

    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    hConnect = connect(s, (struct sockaddr*)&sin, sizeof(sin));


    char buffer[8000];// tried setting higher,  doesn't change anything
    memset(buffer, '\0', 8000);
    recv(s, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0); // <------8k max,  need 64k
```

Comment: There's never any guarantee that a call to `recv()` will fill the buffer. You have to be prepared for short reads and repeat.

Comment: From the server, I am would like to send 64k.  But the iPhone won't work with that size.

Comment: Of course it will. As I say, just keep calling `recv()`. Keep track of the position within your buffer and note the return value from `recv()` to know how much was received in that particular call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's code to read 64KiB:

```
char* buffer = malloc(65536);
int len = 0;
while (len < 65536)
{
    int rc = recv(s, buffer + len, 65536 - len, 0);
    if (rc == 0)
        break; // connection closed
    else if (rc > 0)
        len += rc;
    else if (errno != EINTR)
    {
        // handle error
        break;
    }
}
```